# Unable to convert cursor UPDATE query to SET operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, set

Procedure is using nested cursor of this structure

```
OPEN FetchReqId
   OPEN FetchYear
      OPEN FetchCountry
      CLOSE FetchCountry  
   CLOSE FetchYear   
   OPEN FetchRegion
   CLOSE FetchRegion  
CLOSE FetchReqId
```

Please find a portion of the procedure

```
DECLARE FetchCountry CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY 
    FROM T_CT_ESTIMATION 
    WHERE REQUEST_EST_ID = @REQUEST_EST_ID 
    ORDER BY COUNTRY

                        OPEN FetchCountry
                        FETCH NEXT FROM FetchCountry INTO @COUNTRY_TEMP
                        WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
                            BEGIN
                                --PRINT 'FOR A PARTICULAR COUNTRY:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::' PRINT @COUNTRY_TEMP
                                --SET @FA_BASE_EXP=0.00
                                --SET @INTVST_EXP=0.00

                                DECLARE FetchEstId CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
                                    SELECT DISTINCT EST_ID FROM T_CT_ESTIMATION WHERE REQUEST_EST_ID=@REQUEST_EST_ID AND COUNTRY=@COUNTRY_TEMP
                                OPEN FetchEstId
                                FETCH NEXT FROM FetchEstId INTO @EST_ID
                                WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
                                    BEGIN
                                        --PRINT 'FOR A PARTICULAR EST ID ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
                                        PRINT @EST_ID
                                        select @INTVST_EXP_TO_ADD=SUM(ROUND(((inner1.cont*inner1.invstExp)+inner1.taxPer+inner1.invstExp)*inner1.CONVERSION_RATE,0))
                                        from
                                        (select ((case when e.MAINT_HW_MAINFRAME is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_MAINFRAME end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_STORAGE is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_STORAGE end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_SERV_WINDWS is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_SERV_WINDWS end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_SERV_UNIX is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_SERV_UNIX end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_SERV_LINUX is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_SERV_LINUX end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_PC is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_PC end)+
                                        ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_DATACNTR,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER end)+
                                        (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA end)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP end)+
                                        (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING end)+
                                        ISNULL(EXP_CONTRACT_CONSULT,0)+ISNULL(EXP_INTERNAL_LABOUR,0)+ISNULL(CROS,0)+ISNULL(MACD,0)+ISNULL(PROF_SERVICES,0)+ISNULL(OTHER_EXP_ELEMENT,0)) as invstExp,
                                        EXP_CONTI_PER/100 as cont,
                                        ((EXP_SALE_TAX_VAT/100)*(ISNULL(MAINT_HW_MAINFRAME,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_STORAGE,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_SERV_WINDWS,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_SERV_UNIX,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_SERV_LINUX,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_PC,0)+
                                        ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_DATACNTR,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER end)+
                                        (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA end)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP end)+
                                        (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING end)+ISNULL(CROS,0)+ISNULL(OTHER_EXP_ELEMENT,0))) as taxPer,
                                        CONVERSION_RATE,e.COUNTRY
                                        from T_CT_REQUEST_ESTIMATION r,T_CT_ESTIMATION e 
                                        where r.REQUEST_EST_ID=e.REQUEST_EST_ID and Year=@YR and COUNTRY=@COUNTRY_TEMP and r.REQUEST_ID= @REQID and e.EST_ID=@EST_ID) inner1    

                                        IF(@INTVST_EXP_TO_ADD = NULL)
                                        BEGIN
                                            SELECT @INTVST_EXP_TO_ADD = 0.00
                                        END

                                        select @FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD=SUM(ROUND((inner1.totFaBase+inner1.contPer+inner1.taxPer)*inner1.CONVERSION_RATE,0))
                                        from
                                        (select (ISNULL(MAINT_HW_DISTR_LAN,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_WAN_NTWRK,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_TELECOM,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_NTWRK,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_NTWRK is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_NTWRK end)+isnull(CIRCUITS,0)) as totFaBase,
                                        (ISNULL(MAINT_HW_DISTR_LAN,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_WAN_NTWRK,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_TELECOM,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_NTWRK,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_NTWRK is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_NTWRK end)+ISNULL(CIRCUITS,0) )*(ISNULL(EXP_CONTI_PER,0)/100) as contPer,
                                        (ISNULL(MAINT_HW_DISTR_LAN,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_WAN_NTWRK,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_TELECOM,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_NTWRK,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_NTWRK is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_NTWRK end)+ISNULL(CIRCUITS,0) )*(ISNULL(EXP_SALE_TAX_VAT,0)/100) as taxPer,
                                        CONVERSION_RATE,COUNTRY
                                        from T_CT_REQUEST_ESTIMATION r,T_CT_ESTIMATION e 
                                        where r.REQUEST_EST_ID=e.REQUEST_EST_ID and Year=@YR and COUNTRY=@COUNTRY_TEMP and r.REQUEST_ID=@REQID and e.EST_ID=@EST_ID) inner1 

                                        IF(@FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD = NULL)
                                        BEGIN
                                            SELECT @FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD = 0.00
                                        END

                                        IF(@COUNTRY_TEMP='US' OR @COUNTRY_TEMP='BELGIUM')
                                        BEGIN
                                            SET @INTVST_EXP= @INTVST_EXP+ @INTVST_EXP_TO_ADD
                                            SET @FA_BASE_EXP=@FA_BASE_EXP+@FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD
                                            PRINT 'YES COUNTRY IS EITHER US OR BELGIUM:::: ' PRINT @INTVST_EXP PRINT @FA_BASE_EXP
                                        END
                                        ELSE
                                        BEGIN
                                            select @FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD=SUM((TOTAL_EXP*CONVERSION_RATE)) from T_CT_REQUEST_ESTIMATION r,T_CT_ESTIMATION e
                                            where r.REQUEST_EST_ID=e.REQUEST_EST_ID and YEAR=@YR
                                            and COUNTRY=@COUNTRY_TEMP
                                            and REQUEST_ID=@REQID
                                            and e.EST_ID=@EST_ID

                                            SET @FA_BASE_EXP=@FA_BASE_EXP+@FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD
                                            PRINT '@INTVST_EXP::::: for Country Other than US and Belgium' PRINT @INTVST_EXP
                                            PRINT '@FA_BASE_EXP:::::' PRINT @FA_BASE_EXP
                                        END

                                        --PRINT 'INVEST EXPENSE TO ADD:::::::::' PRINT @INTVST_EXP_TO_ADD
                                        --PRINT 'FA BASE EXPENSE TO ADD:::::::::' PRINT @FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD

                                        --PRINT 'FOR A PARTICULAR EST ID ENDED====================================================='                                        
                                    FETCH NEXT FROM FetchEstId
                                    INTO @EST_ID
                                    END 

                                CLOSE FetchEstId
                                DEALLOCATE FetchEstId

                                --PRINT 'FOR A PARTICULAR COUNTRY END================================================='
                            FETCH NEXT FROM FetchCountry
                            INTO @COUNTRY_TEMP
                            END

                        CLOSE FetchCountry
                        DEALLOCATE FetchCountry
```

SET @SQL = ''

```
                        /*SET @SQL = N'UPDATE T_CT_TEMP_ADHOC SET Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_Capital = '+cast(@USD_TOT_CAP as varchar(1000))+',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_Expense = '+cast(@USD_TOT_EXP as varchar(1000))+' ,Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'='+@YR+'WHERE ID = ' +@SESSNID+' AND REQUEST_ID = '''+@REQID+''''*/


                        --TO CHANGE UPDATE QUERY AND ADD FA BAse EXP and INvestMent Exp for All years as splitted. 
                        --Also create Variables in Code and get it to display in Report Page
                        SET @SQL = N'UPDATE T_CT_TEMP_ADHOC SET Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_Capital = '+cast(@USD_TOT_CAP as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_Expense = '+cast(@USD_TOT_EXP as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_MAINT_HW = '+cast(@USD_ONG_HW as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_MAINT_SW = '+cast(@USD_ONG_SW as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_EXPENSED_CONTRACT_CONSULT = '+cast(@USD_ONG_EXP_CONT_CONSLT as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_EXPENSED_INTER_LABOUR = '+cast(@USD_ONG_EXP_INTRNL_LBR as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_CROS = '+cast(@USD_ONG_EXP_CROS as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_CIRCUITS = '+cast(@USD_ONG_EXP_CIRCTS as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_ONG_EXP_SALE_AMNT = '+cast(@USD_ONG_EXP_SALES_AMOUNT as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'='+@YR+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_FA_BASE_SPLIT_EXP='+cast(@FA_BASE_EXP as varchar(1000))+
                                    ',Year'+cast(@Countr as varchar(10))+'_INVST_SPLIT_EXP='+cast(@INTVST_EXP as varchar(1000))+
                                    ' WHERE ID = ' +@SESSNID+' AND REQUEST_ID = '''+@REQID+''''


                        print 'FFF'
                        PRINT @SQL

                        EXEC sp_executesql
                        @query = @SQL

                        SET @Countr = @Countr+1
                        SET @FA_BASE_EXP=0
                        SET @INTVST_EXP=0
                        SET @FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD=0

                FETCH NEXT FROM FetchYear INTO @YR,@REQUEST_EST_ID
                END 
                CLOSE FetchYear
                DEALLOCATE FetchYear
```

Now i have modified one query as

```
    select 

  SUM(ROUND(((inner1.cont*inner1.invstExp)+inner1.taxPer+inner1.invstExp)*inner1.CONVERSION_RATE,0))
                                            from
                                            (select inner1.EST_ID,((case when e.MAINT_HW_MAINFRAME is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_MAINFRAME end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_STORAGE is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_STORAGE end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_SERV_WINDWS is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_SERV_WINDWS end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_SERV_UNIX is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_SERV_UNIX end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_SERV_LINUX is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_SERV_LINUX end)+(case when e.MAINT_HW_PC is null then 0 else MAINT_HW_PC end)+
                                            ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_DATACNTR,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER end)+
                                            (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA end)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP end)+
                                            (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING end)+
                                            ISNULL(EXP_CONTRACT_CONSULT,0)+ISNULL(EXP_INTERNAL_LABOUR,0)+ISNULL(CROS,0)+ISNULL(MACD,0)+ISNULL(PROF_SERVICES,0)+ISNULL(OTHER_EXP_ELEMENT,0)) as invstExp,
                                            EXP_CONTI_PER/100 as cont,
                                            ((EXP_SALE_TAX_VAT/100)*(ISNULL(MAINT_HW_MAINFRAME,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_STORAGE,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_SERV_WINDWS,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_SERV_UNIX,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_SERV_LINUX,0)+ISNULL(MAINT_HW_PC,0)+
                                            ISNULL(MAINT_HW_OTHER_DATACNTR,0)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_OTHER end)+
                                            (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_DATA end)+(case when e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_CLIENT_COMP end)+
                                            (case when e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING is null then 0 else e.MAINT_SW_APP_SERV_ENGINEERING end)+ISNULL(CROS,0)+ISNULL(OTHER_EXP_ELEMENT,0))) as taxPer,
                                            CONVERSION_RATE,e.COUNTRY
                                            from T_CT_REQUEST_ESTIMATION r,T_CT_ESTIMATION  e group by e.EST_ID
                                            where r.REQUEST_EST_ID=e.REQUEST_EST_ID and Year=@YR and COUNTRY=@COUNTRY_TEMP and r.REQUEST_ID= @REQID and e.EST_ID in (** SELECT DISTINCT EST_ID FROM T_CT_ESTIMATION WHERE REQUEST_EST_ID=@REQUEST_EST_ID AND COUNTRY=@COUNTRY_TEMP**)) inner1 group by EST_ID inner1
```

So basically i'm trying to replace cursors by select in statements.
But i'm unable to understand how to replace @SQL update statement as currently it updates data row by row after it receives values through on the fly calculations.
How can the data in upload be done in bulk ?

Comment: no in this update is not simple join. calculation is made on each line of value received from select query.then its being updated

Comment: The suggested duplicate is NOT the same thing at all.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can help but wow....this is a massive wall of text. So much code and so little formatting. For starters get rid of the dynamic sql, it is doing nothing here but adding an extra layer of complexity when it isn't needed. The issue with helping is that we don't have any context. What are all these variables? Are they being set inside the cursor or being passed in? This sure looks like a single update statement would be possible but no idea where to start. Maybe here? http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: did you try not using a cursor? using set based solution

Comment: Hi ..thanks for the comments..here we are getting two expense values INTVST_EXP_TO_ADD and FA_BASE_EXP_TO_ADD by implementing the calculation logic for a list of est ids selected from a cursor ..
Lets say
est id 1 investment ex 1
est id 2 investment ex 2 
and so on 
after that we are trying to update line by line values into another table

Comment: @maSTAShuFu we are trying not to use CURSORS as its taking too much time

Comment: @Sean Lange we are setting the variables inside cursor itself

Comment: Right...so provide us with ALL the details. We can't you find a complete answer with only a partial question. See the link I posted earlier and help us help you.

Comment: @Sean Lange Here we have a particular ReqId : Ex 1001 for this we have 2 EST_ID s EST_ID 1,EST_ID 2 ---we are using the values one by one..first we are using value EST_ID 1 to find out different costs from cost table. Then we are adding costs (x+y+z+..including calculations )$ to form investment expense and base business expense .So costs are unique for each EST_ID for cursor.Now previously we used to take values one by one and execute update.But now I tried to calculate all values at one go(select in statement) .But UPDATE is still inserting one at a time.Please let me know for any queries.

Comment: I have asked previously for details. You are just throwing some vague text at this and asking for somebody to provide you with a query. YOU need to put some effort into this. I understand you want to stop using a cursor for your updates and I commend you for that. But I can't just magically pull a set based query out of thin air. I have no tables, no data, no rules other than what is scattered through your partial code above. Put yourself in my shoes and ask yourself if you really think you have provided enough information.